# Mount External "My Passport for Mac" to VM Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, mount, hard-drive, mac

I am struggling trying to figure out how to mount my external mac drive to my virtual Ubuntu 14 Desktop. I am using VM Workstation 10 and have updated my Ubuntu desktop to the most current release.

Here is what I know so far.

```
sudo -s
mount -t hfsplus /dev/
```

The HD is plugged into a USB port however I am unsure how to find out what the dir extension would be for this drive.

Any tips would be appreciated. I am very new to Linux and I am trying to learn a lot but it seems tough to get my head wrapped around at times.

Thanks in advance!

Chris

**Update:**

After some further research, here is what I was able to find after running lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I still have yet to find a way for the VM to see the Device in order to mount it. 
Is this an issue with VM Workstation because I am running it on Windows 8.1?

Comment: Are you sure that you actually alllow Ubuntu to see that drive? Check in *Devices* (or similar) menu entry of **Virtual Machine** software.

Comment: @julka I am running Windows 8 so I can not see the drive on my host machine.

Comment: See my update posted in the original article

Answer (score 0):

Note that I use neither Windows 8, nor Mac. Information for Step 2 was found by **googling** and checking **Ubuntu Software Center**.

Step 1: Try `lsblk` from Ubuntu to check all devices and partitions in them it sees.
Step 2: Check if software needed to read Mac drives is installed (and install if not)

- [By default](http://guides.macrumors.com/File_systems) Mac drives uses `hfs+` journalling system, not understood natively by Ubuntu.
- `sudo apt-get install hfsplus`
- also try `sudo apt-get install hfsprogs`

"Step 3": If you checked that your host sees the drive, but guest when you virtually attach does not, it most probably is an issue with the virtualisation software. List item

Comment: I have done these steps already so I am guessing as you mentioned, it is an issue with the Virtual Workstation. 

I will keep updating as i learn more, in case anyone else has an issue similar to this.